# Only half the revenue data gets logged in Google Analytics ecommerce

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce

I am sending the following data to Google Analytics to register ecommerce transactions:

First of all transaction data:

```
'form_params' => [
                'v' => $gaVersion,
                'tid' => $gaId,
                'cid' => $client->getId(),
                't'   => 'transaction',
                'ti'  => $transaction->getId(),
                'tr'  => $transaction->getPrice(),
                'cu'  => 'EUR'

            ],
```

Then item data:

```
'form_params' => [
                    'v' => $gaVersion,
                    'tid' => $gaId,
                    'cid' => $client->getId(),
                    't'   => 'item',
                    'in'  => $transaction->getName(),
                    'ti'  => $transaction->getId(),
                    'ip'  => $transaction->getPrice(),
                    'iv'  => $transaction->getCategory(),
                    'ic'  => $transaction->getSku(),
                    'iq'  => $transaction->getQuantity(),
                    'cu'  => 'EUR'

                ],
```

Each transaction for me only ever has one item. I push the from backend, using the measurement protocol.

Only about half the revenue gets shown in analytics dashboard. Any ideas what could be wrong? Anyone had a problem where not all data would be shown in dashboard?

Comment: Is this data sent to GA from your server, or by the client web browser?   It looks like PHP code which makes me think server, but GA data is usually sent client side.